# Passing status to a widget in Bottom Modal Sheet

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, state

I have a bottom modal sheet that shows a grid of GridItem widgets that are highlighted upon being selected, and I want it to remain selected when I close the sheet and reopen it, but I'm unable to achieve this.

Here is the code for the sheet and the ModalSheet and the Grid Item:

```
  _bottomSheet(context){
    showModalBottomSheet(context: context,
        isScrollControlled: true,
        useSafeArea: true,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0)),
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF6946EC),
        builder: (BuildContext c){
      return Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.6,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              GridView.builder(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
                      maxCrossAxisExtent: 200
                  ),
                  itemCount: comList.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext c,int index){
                    return  GridItem(
                        item: comList[index],
                        isSelected: (bool value){
                          setState(() {
                            if(value){
                              selectedCache.add(comList[index]);
                            } else{
                              selectedCache.remove(comList[index]);
                            }
                          });
                        });
                  }
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 65),
                child: ElevatedButton(
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.lightGreen,
                      elevation: 20.0,
                      textStyle: const TextStyle(
                        color: Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
                        fontSize: 22.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                        fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
                      ),
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0)
                      ),
                    ),
                    onPressed: (){
                      setState(() {
                        for(var com in selectedCache){
                          selectedList.add(com);
                        }
                      });
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    },
                    child: const Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                      child: Text('Confirm'),
                    )
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    });
  }
  
  class GridItem extends StatefulWidget {
  final String item;
  final ValueChanged<bool> isSelected;

  GridItem({required this.item, required this.isSelected});

  @override
  _GridItemState createState() => _GridItemState();
}

class _GridItemState extends State<GridItem> {
  bool isSelected = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5,5,5,5),
      child: GestureDetector(
        child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(
                color: isSelected==true ? Colors.lightGreenAccent : Colors.grey,
                width: 2,
              ),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
            ),
            child:InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  isSelected = !isSelected;
                  widget.isSelected(isSelected);
                });
              },
              child: Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Center(child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Text(widget.item),
                  )),
                  isSelected
                      ? const Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(3, 3, 0 , 0),
                        child: Icon(
                            Icons.check_circle,
                            color: Colors.green,
                            size: 15.0,
                        ),
                      )
                      : Container()
                ],
              ),
            )
        )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried assigning a separate property *highlight* that is true if the item is in the selected cache but that affects the default behavior of it being selected, so I'm unsure of how to proceed. I appreciate any input you may have!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a bool typed class variable in GridItem class, which will have the check if the following GridItem is selected or not.

you can name it as 'isItemSelected', and you may change the name of 'isSelected' variable name() to 'onClick' as it's a function for selecting and deselecting the item.

you can refer to the below code for GridItem class:

```
  class GridItem extends StatefulWidget {
  final ValueChanged<bool> onClick;
  final String item;
  final bool isItemSelected;

  const GridItem(
      {super.key, required this.item, required this.onClick, required this.isItemSelected});

  @override
  _GridItemState createState() => _GridItemState();
}

class _GridItemState extends State<GridItem> {
  late bool isItemSelected;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    isItemSelected = widget.isItemSelected;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 5, 5, 5),
      child: GestureDetector(
          child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(
                  color: isItemSelected ? Colors.lightGreenAccent : Colors.grey,
                  width: 2,
                ),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
              ),
              child: InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    isItemSelected = !isItemSelected;
                    widget.onClick(isItemSelected);
                  });
                },
                child: Stack(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Center(child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Text(widget.item),
                    )),
                    isItemSelected
                        ? const Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(3, 3, 0, 0),
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.check_circle,
                        color: Colors.green,
                        size: 15.0,
                      ),
                    )
                        : Container()
                  ],
                ),
              )
          )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! The widgets are working as expected now :)